# Codeigniter AJAX Example

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I've been looking for a week now for a decent full working example of how to use AJAX with Codeigniter (I'm an AJAX novice). The posts / tuts I've seen are old - all the programming languages have moved on.

I want to have an input form on a page which returns something to the page (e.g. a variable, database query result or html formatted string) without needing to refresh the page. In this simple example is a page with an input field, which inserts the user input into a database. I'd like to load a different view once the input is submitted. If I could understand how to do this I'd be able to adapt it to do whatever I needed (and hopefully it would help others too!)

I have this in my 'test' controller:

```
function add(){
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    if( $name ) {
        $this->test_model->put( $name );
    }
}

function ajax() {
    $this->view_data["page_title"] = "Ajax Test";
    $this->view_data["page_heading"] = "Ajax Test";

    $data['names'] = $this->test_model->get(); //gets a list of names
    if ( $this->input->is_ajax_request() ) { 
        $this->load->view('test/names_list', $data);
    } else {
        $this->load->view('test/default', $data);
    }
}
```

Here is my view, named 'ajax' (so I access this through the URL www.mysite.com/test/ajax)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
       jQuery('#submit').click( function( e ) {
           e.preventDefault();
           var msg = jQuery('#name').val();
           jQuery.post("
               <?php echo base_url(); ?>
               test/add", {name: msg}, function( r ) {
                   console.log(r);
               });
           });
       });
</script>

<?php echo form_open("test/add"); ?>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

All that happens currently is that I type in an input, updates the database and displays the view "test/default" (it doesn't refresh the page, but doesn't display "test/names_list" as desired. Many thanks in advance for any help, and for putting me out of my misery!

Comment: Really your controller only set array values. Where do you load your views? (I'm only using jQuery for ajax which would reduce your js code to 1/10 of now)

Comment: On this occasion, i'l recommend jquery. Or else, open up the js console in browser and look at the errors.

Comment: Views are loaded automatically in my controllers, as I have this function in a main controller to do it:     // set the default content view
    if ( $this->content_view !== FALSE && empty($this->content_view) ){
         $this->content_view = $this->router->class . '/' . $this->router->method;
     }

    // render the content view
    $yield = file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/' . $this->content_view . EXT) ? $this->load->view($this->content_view, $this->view_data, TRUE) : FALSE;

Comment: Please could you suggest the appropriate jQuery code which would achieve what I'm trying to do in this example? The jQuery examples I have tried from other sites have been flawed but I'm not good enough to write it myself

Comment: Look at the jquery in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352404/codeigniter-ajax-form-submitting-form

Comment: Not free, but net tuts is a great resource  https://tutsplus.com/tutorial/ajax-user-table-management-with-codeigniter-and-jquery/

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've spent the last hour reviewing the article posted by @jtheman and have now updated my original post - the problem is slightly different now!

Comment: change `jQuery('#submit').click(function(e){` to `jQuery('#submit').parents('form').submit(function(e){`

Comment: @eicto that causes a submission with a redirect to www.mysite.com/test/add and since I don't have a view for the "add" function it kicks in my 404 page

Comment: I mean generated page with the form, www.mysite.com/test/ajax

Comment: hm may be your question is simplier than i though...

Comment: where you want to show "different view" ?

Comment: @eicto on the same page www.mysite.com/test/ajax, just to load the "names_list" view instead of the "default" view after the user submits their input

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21165/discussion-between-eicto-and-whispersan)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set unique id to the form:

```
echo form_open('test/add', array('id'=>'testajax'));
```

I assume that you want replace a form with a view:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var $=jQuery;
$('#testajax').submit(function(e){
    var $this=$(this);
    var msg = $this.find('#name').val();
    $.post($this.attr('action'), {name: msg}, function(data) {
      $this.replace($(data));
    });
    return false;
});
```

better way if you return url of view in json response:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/add", {name: msg}, function(data) {
  $this.load(data.url);
},"json");
```

---

from your last comment - I **strongly** not suggest to replace body, it will be very hard to support such code.

but here is anser:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/add", {name: msg}, function(data) {
      $('body').replace(data);
    });
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help and discussion!

Comment: instead of `var $=jQuery;`, you could open the ready statement passing `$` as argument, like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` :)

Comment: try this tutorial http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/