# ajax POST success result not logging

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm making an ajax post to a php page. On the php page I echo the result so the success call back will log it, but it doesn't work.

JS:

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url : "http://XXXXXXX/bn/sample.php",
        type : 'POST',
        number: "1234567",
        success : function (result) {
           console.log("success"); 
           console.log(result);
        },
        error : function () {
           alert("error");
        }
    });
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$data = $_POST['number'];

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Answered here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887095/codeigniter-ajax-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're setting `number` as a attribute in your AJAX json object. The correct attribute is `data`:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "http://XXXXXXX/bn/sample.php",
    type : 'POST',
    data: {number: "1234567"},
    success : function (result) {
       console.log("success"); 
       console.log(result);
    },
    error : function () {
       alert("error");
    }
});
```