# Variables to DB and back codeigniter with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Ok, so I have a table that looks like this:

```
echo "<table id='tbl'>";

foreach ($questions as $q1)
{
    if($q1->parinte==0)
    {
        echo "<tr class=".clickable">";
        echo "<td class='parrent".$q1->parinte."' id='".$q1->id."'>".$q1->text."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

The questions variable is passed from my controller and used here.

What I want is when i click a row in that table, I want to check the id of that row with something from my database and then rewrite the table with other rows from my database.
I think it's simplier in jQuery but I kinda new to jQuery and Codeigniter.

Can someone give me an example on how to send the ID when I click a row and compare to something in my database?

Thanks.

LE:

My model:

```
class Support_help_model extends CI_Model
{

public function get_questions()
    {
        //Intrebari principale
        $query = $this -> db -> query("SELECT * FROM decision_tree");
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
class Support_help_controller extends CI_Controller 
{

public function index()
{
    $this->load->model("support_help_model");

    $data['questions'] = $this->support_help_model->get_questions();

    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}

}
```

Comment: You can use jquery bind a click event, and use ajax call php to check this data. You can search about `ajax with php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick` of the row, send the variable to your php script (save.php) using [**ajax**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). Just like this-

```
$(".parrent0").click(function() {
    $.post( "save.php", { param: this.id }, function( data ) {
        alert(data); // here you'll get the db rows returned
    });
});
```

Receiving the variable and returning the result back; **save.php**-

```
$param = $_POST['param'];

//
// db queries
//

$db_data; // data/rows to be returned back
echo json_encode($db_data);
```

Comment: Well, I have my function like:

$(".parrent0").click(function()
 {
    
  //console.log(this.id);

 });

And this returns my id from the row i click. I will look at that ajax. My problem is that I don't know how to send the variable and to check in my DB then return some rows from the DB.

Comment: I'll try and I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question with my model and my controller. If I redirect it to my controller, my data from my function is my whole controller code. I knew that the method only works when you are in pure PHP, not MVC.

Comment: What's the difference? You can of-course use this with your MVC arch. For ex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887095/codeigniter-ajax-example

Comment: But how,  you are returning from the controller class right? There must be something wrong you are doing here, pl check carefully

Comment: I'm using this code: $.post( "support_help_controller", { param: this.id }, function( data ) {
        alert(data); // here you'll get the db rows returned
    });
 });

It should go to my controller, make the query then return the rows, right?

This is the thing I don't understand. I doesn't seems right to me. Sorry, I'm new with all this.

Comment: I managed to send my id to the controller but how can i acces my $db_data from my view so I can replace the results in my table?

Comment: I think you can directly change the value of the object that is binded to the view.